# dual monitor setup - digital & hdmi inputs - one graphics card

Tags: hdmi, multiple-monitors

i have an issue with two monitors (both LG e2441) i just bought and connected.
[image]

the monitor 1 is connected to hdmi, the monitor 2 to digital.

**the issue is that while they are both set to the same recommended resolution, on monitor 1 the image is somehow 'smaller' meaning the text is slightly smaller, and around the actual desktop there is an inch or two of black unused space, while this is not the case on the monitor 2 - there the text is nicely sized, readable and there is no unused monitor space.**

how to fix that?

the graphics card is ati radeon hd 5670.

thnx

Answer (score 1):

here is what the issue was... overscan gets set to ~10% for some reason. moving it to 0 fixes the issue.

[image]